# gradle how to predict a directory whether contains a file

Tags: android, gradle

In gradle, in android project, if libs doesn't contain **android-support-v13.jar**, I will copy **android-support-v4.jar** to destination directory. But I don't know how to do. The following is code:

```
task showLib << {
    def FileTree tree = fileTree(dir:'libs')
    if(tree.contains(file('android-support-v13.jar'))){
       println 'do nothing'
    }
    else{
        println "copy android-support-v4.jar to dest"
    }
}
```

**libs** directory has an android-support-v13.jar, but the output is else clause. I don't know why.

Thanks

**EDIT**

I make a mistake, **file('android-support-v13.jar')** should be **file('libs/android-support-v14.jar')**

Sorry for noise

Comment: What exactly you don't know how to do?

Comment: @Opal, the code doesn't work correctly, I don't know why

Comment: @Opal, thank you. I found the mistake